# Check User Credentials Without Logging In

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

Is there any way to check if a user's username and password are valid without logging them in? Using:

import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
Auth.signIn(email, password);

Has the issue whereby upon calling that user is signed in causing the currently signed in user to be displaced. Is there a way to perhaps leverage Auth.signIn() to check if the credentials are correct without progressing to the full signin or even signing them in and signing them out immediately?

Comment: Could you clarify your goal? I am struggling to understand your use-case.

Comment: @Luke There are instances when you need to confirm password for a user in an application when the user is already signed in. So whether there is an endpoint to validate the user credential without actually logging in the user again.

Comment: const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(); -> https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/